# Timestamp in Between Join SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, time-series

How do I join `Table B` on `Table A` where `Table B` has timestamps in-between `Table A's` timestamps? I am using SQL Server 2008.

Table A

```
Start               End
---------------------------------------
2022-04-29 15:00:00 2022-04-29 15:30:00
2022-04-29 15:30:00 2022-04-29 17:00:00
2022-04-29 17:00:00 2022-04-29 18:00:00
2022-04-29 18:00:00 2022-04-29 18:30:00
2022-04-29 18:30:00 2022-04-29 20:00:00
```

Table B

```
Start             Value
-----------------------
2022-04-29 12:00:00 100
2022-04-29 15:30:00 200
2022-04-29 16:00:00 300
2022-04-29 18:00:00 400
2022-04-29 21:00:00 500
```

Desired result - product of Table A and B:

```
Start               End                Value
--------------------------------------------
2022-04-29 15:00:00 2022-04-29 15:30:00 200
2022-04-29 15:30:00 2022-04-29 17:00:00 300
2022-04-29 17:00:00 2022-04-29 18:00:00 NaN
2022-04-29 18:00:00 2022-04-29 18:30:00 400
2022-04-29 18:30:00 2022-04-29 20:00:00 NaN
```

Comment: Have you considered the `>=` and `<`/`<=` operators?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 (on prem) went out of _extended security update_ support a month ago, SP4 std support 3+ years ago.  You should really consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to decide on whether or not the top ranges are inclusive or not (see Larnu's comment)  `>= and <`  will generate different results than `> and <=`

```
Select A.*
      ,B.Value
 From TableA A
 Left Join TableB B on B.Start  >= A.Start
                    and B.Start <  A.[End]
```

**Results**

[image]